# OleDbDataReader inside a OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I have 2 Tables. I want to get all ID's from Table1, and while I am inside the frist OleDbCommand I want to check if the ID is in Table2 too.
I tried this:

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE NAME=:NAME)
{
 ............
   decimal dId = (decimal)odr["ID"];
   using (OleDbCommand cmdE = new OleDbCommand("SELECT LOGID FROM Table2 WHERE ID:=ID", con))
   cmdE.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmdE.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("ID", dId));
   decimal cId=-1;
   using (OleDbDataReader odrE = cmdE.ExecuteReader())
   {
    while (odrE.Read())
    {
     cId = (decimal)odrE["ID"];
    }...............
```

The Problem is that

```
 cId = (decimal)odrE["ID"];
```

is never executed, even though if I do a manaul Select inside the Sql Developer i get results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: plz make  the code CLEAR to understand

Comment: Are you getting any error ? and please be more clear.

Comment: Did you debug your code line by line?

Comment: No, i don't get any error message. odrE.Read() doesn't contain any value.

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong syntax for parameters in OLEDB. Try

```
using (OleDbCommand cmdE = new OleDbCommand("SELECT LOGID FROM Table2 WHERE ID=@ID", con))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using a OleDbCommand inside a OleDbCommand. Using a OUTER JOIN solved the problem. Thank you